# How can i catch mouse wheel click event in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, click, mouseevent, mousewheel

How can I catch **mouse wheel click event** in flex?
I use

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL,function(){});
```

But It works not,

Thanx

Answer (score 4):

MIDDLE_CLICK event [in AIR 1.0, Flash Player **11.2** and later versions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#MIDDLE_CLICK)

[Middle click support in 11.1 and earlier versions of Flash Player via JavaScript](http://forums.adobe.com/message/1929244#1929244#1929244)